# This seems on topic, what is off topic about it?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I can't figure out how this question could possibly be off topic. What am I missing? I wouldn't have closed it if it popped in my review queue, I might have told them to fix it in any number of ways, but it doesn't seem even a tiny bit off-topic.

Even regardless that I answered the question before it was closed, but that makes it even more confusing as to why it was set off-topic.

[text foreground ColorAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383373/text-foreground-coloranimation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you see the following paragraph of text in the bottom half of the blue “closed” notice box?

> Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.

That is the detailed description of why the question was closed as off-topic. It is the reason given/chosen by the close voters.

Essentially, the question was closed because it does not contain a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Yes, it is confusing that this close reason is a sub-category if “off topic”. Off-topic suggests that the question is not programming related, but it clearly is. The problem with it is that it doesn’t contain enough information and/or doesn’t fit into our [specific requirements for a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Why that specific issue is confusingly shoved under “off-topic” is a UX battle that I’ve fought before many times, but lost.

Comment: That's odd. Why is that a losing battle? It seems like would be a change that people would support.

Comment: And no, I can't see that text. This is all I see. "Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers. Want to improve this question? Update the question so it's on-topic for Stack Overflow. Closed 19 days ago." That makes the whole refusal for a better category even worse. o.O I didn't ask it, I answered it so I assume that is why I don't see the reason, but it doesn't look like I can even dig into it somewhere to find the reason and I am forced to ask here instead.

Comment: @Rodger I guess the full text of the closure notice is only "_viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege_". Since you have <3k rep, you can't see it (but it's there).

Comment: Wonky "how did these people even *see* the question" case number 3.

Comment: @HansPassant - I answered it before it was closed with "not enough info to answer" as the reason. The answer was accepted as working also. So... yeah, it had enough info to answer, it just wasn't written very well. I probably couldn't see it now if I didn't have a link to it in my answers section/mailbox/activity log.

Comment: @GinoMempin - yeah, I saw that 3k requirement for closing but didn't know that it also causes only part of the closure reason to display. I'll keep it in mind when it happens again.

Comment: Gotta love the community for punishing me for being such a jerk as to ask this question with a downvote on the answer that I posted BEFORE IT WAS CLOSED.

Comment: @Rodger Downvotes aren't punishment, and you have no real reason to suspect that the downvote on the answer was at all related to the question having been closed. More likely, the downvoter just didn't find your answer to be helpful. Regarding losing the battle, I don't know. It's been this way for years. I suspect it's a technical limitation where the only close reasons that can be customized on each individual site are the "off-topic" reasons. But I'm really not sure. The lawyer-ese answer is that these questions technically *are* off-topic for SO because they don't meet our guidelines.

Comment: @Rodger since you know the answer it should be trivial to you to edit question in shape - at very least including OP's comment on what actually failing, but possibly cleaning up code to be more focused on the problem (editing code is not a good idea, but what other options you have if you feel you must answer the question and hence need question to have MRE)… Clearly OP is not going to do so and noone else but you felt the question is good and useful...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, but since I am not the poster and/or don't have 3k rep I can't get it reopened right? And since it is closed no one will ever see it? Or am I misunderstanding? I'm happy to edit it if it provides value but if nothing comes of it I'll edit questions that are still open instead. :)

Comment: Editing a question that has been closed (or, in your case, having a suggested edit *approved*) places that question into a review queue, where users vote to determine whether or not it should be re-opened. So, editing a closed question is *not* pointless, as long as your edit solves the problem that led to the question getting closed. Also...since this has now been raised on Meta, there are plenty of eyes on the question, almost guaranteeing that it'll be re-opened if appropriate. @Rodger

Comment: @Rodger for insta-re-open you need diamond mod (not going to happen) or standard 3 re-open votes (you may be able to flag for re-open similar to flag-to-close, not sure if there is such option). If it is the first edit after closure the post will be put into re-open queue where (assuming good edit) it likely be re-opened... Now the really hard part is getting edit that post needs to be approved as you need to edit code... that's were 2K would help (also again, that edit would be very borderline acceptable)

Comment: @CodyGray Cool! I didn't realize that. I will tweak it and see if it can be reopened. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov good to know. Either way, as long as it isn't a completely pointless endeavor for me, I'm happy to take a go at fixing it. (also, definitely not worried about instant reopen)